# How to convert get perticular field from PHP array to an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

[image][image]

After click on search button get the mobile number and hit database. if result not null then this fname,lname....all field open with fill form like update form but if result not get it will be open empty....
For that I am write one function on search button this button get mobile number and call one method which in my shipment controller create method using ajax.and in create i get a mobile number and as per result check condition..

```
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['mobilenumber'])) {
    //$modelArray = Customers::find()->where(['cust_mobile' => $_POST['mobilenumber']])->one();
$connection = \Yii::$app->getDb();

$command = $connection->createCommand(
  "SELECT * ".
  "FROM customers AS C ".
  "WHERE C.cust_mobile= " .$_POST['mobilenumber']
           // "AND C.cust_mobile=" .$_POST['mobilenumber2']
  );    
$modelArray = $command->queryAll();

if(count($modelArray) > 0) {

print_r(json_encode($modelArray));
                /*Here I wanna set data which is comming from response i.e in object($modelArray)
                on same form i.e is like a update form i.e here update logic i want to apply*/
            } else {
                /*Here new record is create if enter mobile number is not exist*/
            }

        } else {
    /*open form if mobile number not set*/
        }
    }
```

**Form of add Shipment(shipment/_form.php)**
And In shipment form create button this fname,laname,address all detail save into customer table with shipment id

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function searchResult() {
    var mobilenumber = document.getElementById('customers-cust_mobile').value; 
  $.ajax({

   type: "POST",
   data: {
     mobilenumber: mobilenumber,
   },
  dataType: "json",
   url: "index.php?r=shipment/create",
   success: function(data){
    $('#customers-cust_fname').val(data[0].cust_fname);
    $('#customers-cust_mname').val(data[0].cust_mname);
    $('#customers-cust_lname').val(data[0].cust_lname);
    $('#customers-cust_email').val(data[0].cust_email);
    $('#customers-cust_street').val(data[0].cust_street);
    $('#customers-cust_address').val(data[0].cust_address);

   }
 });
}
    </script>
    <?= $form->field($modelCustomersSender, 'cust_mobile')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
     <?= $form->field($modelCustomersSender, 'cust_fname')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                    <?= $form->field($modelCustomersSender, 'cust_mname')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                    <?= $form->field($modelCustomersSender, 'cust_lname')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code there are a number of non-recommended practices. for example the fact to directly access the $ _POST instead of creating a suitable model and load the values with model-> load or the failure to use the rendering of views to make a ajax action for Update Your data .. in any case the discussion for every aspect would be too long so I give you the code available in the way that I think is closer to the way you write.

You action create could be somethings like this

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    if(isset($_POST['mobilenumber'])) {
        $modelArray = Customers::find()->where(['cust_mobile' => $_POST['mobilenumber']])->one();
        /*Here I got object in which whatever mobile number we enter 
        in text box. as per mobile number i got result and I check a condition is, if result count grater than 0 then 
        form open with fill text field else open with empty field  */
        if(count($modelArray) > 0) {
             $
            /*Here I wanna set data which is comming from response i.e in object($modelArray)
            on same form i.e is like a update form i.e here update logic i want to apply*/
            $modelArray->attribute1 = $_POST['your_attribute1'];
             ......
             $newModel->attributeN = $_POST['your_attributeN'];
             $newModel->save()  
             // redirect or render what you prefer 
             return $this->redirect(['the_view_you_prefer']);              

        } else {
            /*Here new record is create if enter mobile number is not exist*/
             $newModel = new Customers();
             $newModel->mobilenumber =  $_POST['mobilenumber']
             $newModel->attribute1 = $_POST['your_attribute1'];
             ......
             $newModel->attributeN = $_POST['your_attributeN'];
             $newModel->save()
            return $this->redirect(['the_view_you_prefer']);
        }

    } else {
/*open form if mobile number not set*/
    }
}
```

Otherwise  if you only want render the value for ajax you can

```
 myArray['your_attribute1'] = $_POST['your_attribute1'];
 ....
 myArray['your_attributeN'] = $_POST['your_attributeN'];

 $arrayToAjax= json_encode($myArray);
 echo  $arrayToAjax;
```

This should return the json formatted result for your ajax success function

for retrive the data in  success function you can use jsonParse

```
  success: function(data){
         alert(data);//response display here

         var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
         alert(jsonData[0].cust_fname);
         alert(jsonData[0].cust_lname);

       $('customers-cust_lname').val(data);//how to set value fot that text field from response
        // window.location.reload(true);
       }
```

Comment: Thanks...now my creation part is done only update part is reaming and for that my  if(count($modelArray) > 0) {...} condition work properly in ajax response all data is display but i am not able to set this response in text field...I will update ajax function

Comment: I don't understand your comment ... my answer is what you need or  or not?

Comment: Yes you are answer help full for me

Comment: well if my answer is right or useful please rate it ..and for render you data in the view you have two way  or you use the render function properly in you action controller or you use javascript for set the value of  you textInput .... see the code (CTRL+U) for obtain the related field ID

Comment: ID also write but in response lot of field from that only particular field i want na and but how to get value from response it's problem

Comment: You want that the response of the saved values instead of render of a new view is useful for the  ajax request?

Comment: I have update the answer

Comment: I got array but we are not able to set yet particular field from that array I will attach array response

Comment: For set the fileld you need the input text field id and with jquery set the related data .. could be you first must learn how retrive values from data in ajax success function and how set the value in input text ..

Comment: how set I know but I am trouble with retrieve values from data ajax success function...I will try my best after getting I will update code...Thanks

Comment: I have update the answer with some suggestion for retrive the json data

Comment: Ya it's write but data is not coming into this format...This is the problem

Comment: Then try without jsonParse  alert(data[0].cust_fname);

Comment: After adding json it not retuen a data

Comment: I will update my code

Comment: Where adding json ? what json do you refer  ? jsonParse in client? json_decode in server ?

Comment: Thanks..Now it's working I will update my code

Comment: @priyankaahire well if my answer  is right please mark it as accepted and if you think my suggestion are useful please rate iit properly.